# Array.fill(Array) creates copies by references not by value

Tags: javascript, reference, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a 6 by 12 Matrix using `Array.fill`

```
let m = Array(6).fill(Array(12).fill(0));
```

While this works, the problem is that the inner Arrays are actually all referencing the same `Array` object.

```
let m = Array(6).fill(Array(12).fill(0));
m[0][0] = 1;
console.log(m[1][0]); // Outputs 1 instead of 0
```

I wanted (and expected) the value of `m[1][0]` to be `0`.

How can I force `Array.fill` fill copy-by-values of the given argument (eg: `Array(12).fill(0)` is the argument in my case) instead of copying by reference ?

Comment: You can't force `Array.fill()` to do anything other than what it already does. You can write your own function to do it of course.

Comment: @Pointy You are right, a second parameter to fill for "deep-copy" would be useful :)

Comment: It might be nice to be able to pass a generator function of some sort.

Comment: Use lodashes deep clone and it will remove the references

Comment: @WilliamKunkel: In most use cases, you could simply do `Array.from(generator)` instead of something like `Array(6).fillBy(generator, 0, 6)`

Comment: Use minimal examples in StackOverflow. You can reproduce this with a single dimensional array.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) instead:

Thanks to `Pranav C Balan` in the comments for the suggestion on further improving this.

```js
let m = Array.from({length: 6}, e => Array(12).fill(0));

m[0][0] = 1;
console.log(m[0][0]); // Expecting 1
console.log(m[0][1]); // Expecting 0
console.log(m[1][0]); // Expecting 0
```

---

Original Statement (Better optimized above):

```
let m = Array.from({length: 6}, e => Array.from({length: 12}, e => 0));
```

Comment: `let m = Array.from({length: 6}, e => Array(12).fill(0));`

Answer (score 9):

You can't do it with `.fill()`, but you can use `.map()`:

```
let m = new Array(6).map(function() { return new Array(12); });
```

*edit* oh wait that won't work; `.map()` won't iterate through the uninitialized elements. You could fill it first:

```
let m = new Array(6).fill(null).map(function() { return new Array(12); });
```

Comment: `new Array(6).fill().map(...` ? And using arrow functions it actually looks decent.

Comment: @Cristy yes that should work.

Comment: You could do `[...Array(6)].map(() => Array(12).fill(0))`

Comment: This will create a new array, though, rather than mutating it in place.

Comment: You kids with your fancy new language features need to get off my lawn

Comment: As IE will repeatedly remind you

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not using ES6 features that much, but I want to learn them, so whenever I have a project in Node.js or an university project where browser compatibility is not an issue I like experimenting with the new stuff :D

Comment: @Pointy: I think `Array.from(Array(6)).map(…)` is more readable than that ugly spread operator anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with **[`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)** method. Instead iterate over the array and add newly created array using a for loop.

```js
let m = Array(6);
for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
  m[i] = Array(12).fill(0)

m[0][0] = 1;
console.log(m[1][0]);
```

Comment: I know I can create it by using a loop but this is what I wanted to avoid in the first place. :D