# Javascript nested loop not returns outer loop's index as expected

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-loops

```js
const a = 3
const b = 4

const arr = new Array(a).fill([]);

for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < b; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = i;
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

I would expect to return

```js
[[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]]
```

but it returns

```js
[[2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2]]
```

I think this is not because of the closure things but please let me know what is the problem of this code not working as expected.

*** edited -> sorry, I forgot to paste initializing arr code ***

Comment: Where is `arr` defined?

Comment: @Phil Oh I missed it. Would you check it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't assign a value directly in a 2-dimension array. Initialize the first dimension first.

```js
var arr = []
const a = 3
const b = 4

for(let i=0; i<a; i++){
  arr.push([])
  for(let j=0; j<b; j++){
      arr[i][j] = i;
  }
}

console.log(arr)
```

Don't initialize your array like this:

```
const arr = new Array(a).fill([]);
```

By doing this, you pass references and not values, as you could do with integers. The difference between references and values is important.

Comment: I do edit my code. can you check it again? Your code work properly but I cannot understand why my code is still returns the unexpected result..

Comment: I explained the mistake you made.

Comment: Checked! really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I found and post another question about Array.fill() for the other people having the same issue.

[Array.fill(Array) creates copies by references not by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949813/array-fillarray-creates-copies-by-references-not-by-value)