# How to create a 2-D array initialized with zeroes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

Today I was porting my Python code into JavaScript and found this behavior.

Code:

```
var a = new Array(2).fill(new Array(3).fill([0, 0]));
for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
  for (j=0; j<3; j++) {
    a[i][j] = [i, j];
    //console.table(a); //for debugging
  }
}
```

What I think I should get for `a` (as a 2-dim array):

```
--------------------------
[0, 0] | [0, 1] | [0, 2] |
--------------------------
[1, 0] | [1, 1] | [1, 2] |
--------------------------
```

What JavaScript gave me:

```
--------------------------
[1, 0] | [1, 1] | [1, 2] |
--------------------------
[1, 0] | [1, 1] | [1, 2] |
--------------------------
```

It looks like there's some other type of logic used in JavaScript than what I think it should be. I'm simply assigning `[i, j]` to the `[i][j]`-th entry, but the result is not what I have in mind.

1. Have I made a mistake in the code?
2. Why is the for-loop logic doesn't work in JavaScript?
3. What should I do to get the desired result then?

Comment: how do you print out the array contents?

Comment: Because you're using `Array.fill`, `a[1]` is a reference to `a[0]`, so when you change `a[1][0]` you also change `a[0][0]`.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript) for how to properly create an empty 2-d array.

Comment: The key is that `.fill()` does not fill the outer array with *copies* of the inner array, but with references to the same *single* array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we run:

```js
let a = new Array(2).fill(new Array(3).fill([0, 0]));
for (let i=0; i<2; i++) {
  for (let j=0; j<3; j++) {
    a[i][j] = [i, j];
    console.log(a[i][j]);
  }
}
console.log(a);
```

We find that there's nothing wrong with the loop's logic itself. It is going in the correct order for `i` and `j`. So what's the problem? It turns out that JavaScript's `Array.fill()` method [creates copies by references, not values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949813/array-fillarray-creates-copies-by-references-not-by-value)! In other words, each element is basically a reference pointing to the same array, not individual separate arrays. To fix this for your code, use `Array.from()`:

```js
let a = Array.from({length: 2}, e => Array.from({length:3}, e => [0, 0]));
for (let i=0; i<2; i++) {
  for (let j=0; j<3; j++) {
    a[i][j] = [i, j];
    console.log(a[i][j]);
  }
}
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply do this without creating an array with zeroes (unless you need that array with zeroes). Use the `push` method on arrays.

```
let arr = [];
let nrows = 2;
let ncols = 3;

for (let i=0; i<nrows; i++) {
  for (let j=0; j<ncols; j++) {
    arr.push([i,j]);
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```