# Javascript array behaviour

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does this happen? I am trying to create a 2D array with an integer sequence. I know the alternate way to achieve the result, want to know the reason behind this behaviour.
Also, using `new Array(3)` to fill the array shouldn't have caused any reference errors.

```
    let length = 3
    let arrMatrix = (new Array(3)).fill(Array(3));
    arrMatrix.fill((new Array(3)).fill(0));
    var sum = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<length; i++) {
        for(let j=0; j<length; j++) {
            arrMatrix[i][j] = sum;
            sum += 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(arrMatrix);
```

Output

```
[ [ 6, 7, 8 ], [ 6, 7, 8 ], [ 6, 7, 8 ] ]
```

Expected output

```
[ [ 0, 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4, 5 ], [ 6, 7, 8 ] ]
```

Comment: you are filling with same reference. perhaps create a 1D array of 9 and chunk it to 3*3 or array.from

Comment: `const n = 3; const arr = Array.from({ length: n }, (_, i) => Array.from({ length: n }, (_, j) => i * n + j));`

Comment: or `Array.from({length: length}, (e,i) => Array(length).fill().map((_,j) => i*length+j))`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949813/array-fillarray-creates-copies-by-references-not-by-value

Comment: I have an alternate way to do the expected result. Can you guys explain the reason behind the above behaviours.?

Comment: The line `arrMatrix.fill((new Array(3)).fill(0))` fills `arrMatrix` with 3 references to the same array. This means that every child of `arrMatrix` will always look the same, because they are references to the same array.